# How to change Facebook confirmation dialog project name?

Tags: swift, xcode, facebook, facebook-login

How to change below project name?

[image]

Here are some configurations I already did but still showing my previous project name.

```
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>ABCD</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>ABCD</string>
```

EDIT

[image]

Facebook Setting

[image]

Comment: What does your Usage description string look like?

Comment: @MwcsMac I followed above instruction to configure my info.plist. Any additional usage description I need to add?

Comment: Did you try changing it in Facebook Developer Portal? If looking for entire project for the old name does not show any results is probably fetched it from app name at facebook.

Comment: @Jakub Yes. I do updated the name in Facebook. Please see my edit.

Comment: Please check my answer your issue will be solve.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Here is a solution of your question 
just change in info.plist (Tested code)**

```
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>ABCD</string> //Name you want to display
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is 2 solution of your question just change in info.plist (Tested code)

**Method 1** ( for name other than app name)

```
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>ABCD</string>
```

**Method 2** ( for same as app name set in **Your_Project => Build settings => Packaging => Product name** )

```
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
```